# Can I revert changes from the TAKEOWN and ICACLS commands?

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

From the question linked below, [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab) posted a response on how to copy/edit files under Program Files if access is being denied.

> #### [How can I disable access denied when copying from network drive to program files?](https://superuser.com/questions/310011/how-can-i-disable-access-denied-when-copying-from-network-drive-to-program-files/395200#395200)
>
> To do so:
>
> 1. Go to > Start > All Programs > Accessories
> 2. Right-click on Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.
> 3. Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>        takeown /f [path to folder] /r /d y
>    ```
> 4. To assign the Administrators group Full Control Permissions for the folder, use
>      this command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>        icacls [path to folder] /grant administrators:F /T
>    ```

For some dumb reason, I did this to the whole Program Files directory (recursively) instead of the one program folder I was working with.

Is there any way to revert the changes of `TAKEOWN`? Do I just need to enter it again with the "/A" parameter to give ownership to Administrators (assuming that's where it came from)?

Comment: you rather try sfc /Scannow it would restore the Windows part of \ program files. The other programmes should belong to admin or user's groups. you could change it back with icacls  or takeown